# Scraping product image from eCommerce websites

Tags: legal, web-crawling

What are the legal clauses associated with scraping images of products displayed on eCommerce websites (such as Home Depot, Walmart, Amazon, eBay etc)? The intention is to obtain meta-data from the images, and not to reproduce or store them.

Comment: Sorry, voting to close. The legal clauses are *on those websites*. Please do your research there, then if you are left with specific questions, I doubt that these are on-topic here (after all, it's not 'Open data'). You would have to take those questions to [Law.se]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of this comment: "The legal clauses are on those websites. Please do your research there, then if you are left with specific questions, I doubt that these are on-topic here (after all, it's not 'Open data'). You would have to take those questions to Law "